# Do I need an developer Account to try Yosemite developer preview (not the public beta)?

Tags: developer-program, macos

Do I need to have an active developer account to install and use the current Yosemite Developer Preview 7?

I don't mean the public beta.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

See [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) for all the details including information about how to enroll as a developer.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and I know how to enroll as developer. But afaik I was able to install & use Mavericks beta as well without an dev account. And apple even didnt hint that it was possible so I asked. Ty

Comment: You asked for the developer preview. The Mavericks beta versions are more like the public beta of Yosemite.

Comment: Just tried it. It worked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it worked. So you wont need to be listed as developer to install and use the Apple Developer Preview / Beta Builds.

Comment: What URL did you use to download the DP7? (Or perhaps did you redeem a code for it before your developer account expired and are just updating that even though the year has expired?)